# "has" vs "have" usage after enumerating two subjects, the first one in plural

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)

I'm inclined towards the 2nd sentence, because 1) the first subject is plural and 2) there are two subjects.

Sub-question: but what if the first subject would have been singular?

> Specifications and game design has already been completed for it.

or

> Specifications and game design have already been completed for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb should be plural:

> The dog and the cat <strike>was</strike> were sleeping peacefully.
>
> The specifications and design <strike>has</strike> have already been completed.