# What/which problems do/does your organization solve?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, which-what

Which is grammatically correct?

> 1.
>   What problems do your organization solve?
>
> 2.
>   What problems does your organization solve?
>
> 3.
>   Which problems do your organization solve?
>
> 4.
>   Which problems does your organization solve?

Comment: *Organisation* is singular, so *does* must be correct. For *which* or *what,* either fits, but there is not enough information about context to determine whether one is better than the other.

Comment: Similar: [“What questions (is/are) your data team hoping to answer?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80218), [“Which” vs. “what” — what's the difference and when should you use one or the other?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3413)

Answer (score -1):

I respectfully disagree with Andrew. You have to match things up with the object of the sentence. The object in a sentence is the entity that is acted upon by the subject. 'Problems' is the object of this sentence. It is plural so the correct matching is "1. What problems do your organization solve?"

Comment: What do you mean? English has subject-verb agreement, not object-verb agreement.

Comment: The subject, 'problems', receives the action (solving, in this sentence) of the object, 'organization'. The choice of verb depends on the subject - problems. (e.g. What problems do you solve?; What problems do they solve?)

Comment: But "problems" is not the subject. As you say in your answer, " 'Problems' is the **ob**ject of this sentence."