# Using "do" or "does" for two things connected by "and"?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)

> 1. - Does your mother and father know about this?
>    - Do your mother and father know about this?
> 2. - What does "this" and "that" mean?
>    - What do "this" and "that" mean?

Which option is correct? I thought the second one of each example is correct because we are talking about plural things.

Comment: You are quite right. Only the fact that you are in doubt suggests that you may also wish to visit the stackexchange site for [**English language learners**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). This is still under development and not yet accepting questions, but it will do so when interest reaches a critical mass, and your participation would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the plural form of the verb is correct.

> Do your mother and father know about this?
>   What do this and that mean?

This is because as you stated, the sentence is speaking of two things, so the plural is appropriate. The second sentence sounds a bit awkward because "those" would be more natural, but it is still grammatically correct.