# Singular or plural verb with two subjects

Tags: verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using “do” or “does” for two things connected by “and”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90550/using-do-or-does-for-two-things-connected-by-and)

I'm writing an interrogative sentence questioning someone else's writing:

"Is grammar and spelling correct?"

Can I use the singular verb "is" or must it be the plural verb "are"?

(The sentence is one of a list of interrogative questions about the quality of writing, e.g. "Are words in the right order?" "Does the copy flow?")

Answer (score 2):

As a statement it would be plural: *Grammar and spelling are correct.* It remains plural as a question.