# "What {is/are} the meaning and connotations of this phrase?" Which is correct here, "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

Consider the question:

> What is/are the meaning and connotations of this phrase?

---

Clearly you would say:

> What is the meaning of this phrase?
>
> What are connotations of this phrase?

and obviously you could just restructure the sentence to avoid the ambiguity:

> What is the meaning of this phrase, and what are it's connotations?

But supposing you want to use the original phrase, which form of the verb is correct? Is there a correct form?

Comment: There isn't really. One complement is singular, the other plural. Whichever verb form you go for, one will be wrong. Using the plural (_are_) sounds less wrong, as you have two complements, though.

Comment: @OliverMason The verb must agree with its subject, not its complements.

Comment: @NigelJ In the case of link verbs/copula it has to. _What are the meaning of it_ is clearly wrong.

Comment: One can get round the complication of mixed singular/plural by saying 'What would be the meaning and connotations of this phrase ?'

Comment: Related: [Singular verb after two noun phrases joined by “and” that can be thought of as a single thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97459), [Verb agreement in “Where is the Messiah and his Kingdom?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94987), [Using “do” or “does” for two things connected by “and”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90550)