# Correct use of "is" or "are"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)

Would I use *is* or *are* in the following sentence?

> The Pohutakawa Coast, Hauraki Gulf, and Waiheke Island **is/are** the backdrop for our day.

If I rewrote it so the subject (backdrop) starts the sentence, then it seems to me that as it is singular, the verb should be the singular *is*. But as it is written above, *are* seems less clumsy.

Answer (score 3):

You should use *are*, because in your sentence you named three specific names, so if you want to use a pronoun instead of them, that pronoun is *they*, which cannot be used with *is*.

Comment: So if I rewrote it as "The backdrop for our day…" would I still use "are"? As in "The backdrop for our day are the Pohutakawa Coast, the Huaraki Gulf, and Waiheke Island". Doesn't sound quite right to me.

Comment: @DouglasBurns In that case *is* would be correct because you subject is *backdrop*, which is singular.