# Does "is" or "are" introduce a list of items?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

Should a list of items be introduced with *is* or with *are*? Does the verb agree with a singular list or with multiple items in the list?

> Next in the row **is/are** Khorasan-e-‎Razavi, Esfahan, Khuzestan, Fars and East ‎‎Azarbayejan provinces with 5.3, 4.6, 3.9, 3.6 and 2.8 million persons respectively.

Comment: The canonical related question is http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list

Comment: Provide fuller context: preceding lines, especially.

Answer (score 2):

As you are introducing multiple items, you would use *are*, e.g.:

> The remaining teams in the World Cup ***are*** Germany, Argentina, Brazil and Netherlands

You would use is for a single item:

> The next item on the shopping list ***is*** bread

Comment: This is, of course, cheating. You have changed the sentence dramatically by conveniently introducing an all-new subject, "teams", preceding the list. So sure enough it's "the teams are", nobody in his right mind would consider "the teams is". But the original sentence has no "the teams". It has no subject there at all. The subject are the list items themselves.

Comment: You are, of course, free to downvote and supply your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence elides an important noun: *Next* **what** ? Group? Set?

Whatever it is, it is of the nature of a collection and therefore requires the singular for of ***is***.

*meta:* Fuller context could help determine with more confidence. I believe there's a previous direct or indirect reference.