# Using 'is" or "are"

Tags: word-usage

What is the right way to write the following sentence

Profit and Loss Statement and Income Statement **are** the same thing.

Profit and Loss Statement and Income Statement **is** the same thing.

Comment: Neither is correct. At a minimum, you need to use indefinite articles or plural nouns. (And which you use, and where, will also inform the verb to use, and if the sentence should be rephrased to avoid confusion.)

Comment: This is an amusing one. One has to say that '_Profit and loss statement_ and _Income statement_ are the same thing' has a first-order notionally unitary coordinate subject, apparently licensing 'is', but there _are_ two different things being compared – the two different terms. So 'are' is justified, even notionally, and sounds better.

Comment: @Jason 'Compound interest is interest applied yearly say to the running total' needs another article? Aren't we defining terms?

Comment: The complex predicate _(be) the same (thing/person) as_ is a normal commutative verb; it can be transitive with either NP order (_A is the same as B = B is the same as A_), licensing a singular form of _be_; or it can be intransitive, so it licenses a plural form of _be,_ as here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ***A*** *Profit and Loss Statement* or *Profit and Loss* ***Statements***. In the specific sentence in the question, *statement* is a count noun. In your new example, *interest* is a mass noun, which is something entirely different. Unless the question is referring to the phrases (words) themselves rather than using them functionally as part of the sentence grammar. If so, it hasn't been made clear.

Comment: I'd corrected to mention-mode in my comment,  '_Profit and loss statement_ and _Income statement_ are the same thing'. Non-count usages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences need articles, but either way the plural verb is correct since there are two subjects which, coincidentally are the same.

> A profit and loss statement and an income statement are the same thing.

If you are making a general statement.

> The profit and loss statement and the income statement are the same thing.

If you are making a specific statement, about specific statements.

You can use a singular subject to say something similar:

> The profit and loss statement is the same thing as the income statement.

Comment: The use of the definite article in this context, although understandable, isn't entirely idiomatic unless there are referents for the two terms. (Making it demonstrative.)  It would be more natural to drop the article and make the nouns plural.