# Subject–verb agreement: "are" versus "is"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Singular or plural following a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/singular-or-plural-following-a-list)
>   [My apples and orange are wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15769/my-apples-and-orange-are-wrong)

What is correct?

> - Her ripples, her current, her momentum is the fountainhead of science.
> - Her ripples, her current, her momentum are the fountainhead of science.

Answer (score 1):

*Are* is the correct form. And you might even consider the following structure.

> Her ripples, current, and momentum are the fountainhead of science.

Comment: Thanks. What if the list is after the verb and the first in the list is singular? For example: The fountainhead of science is her momentum, her ripples, her current.

Comment: @Essen Example please?

Comment: Please see the example above

Comment: @Essen *is* is correct here.