# Grammatical number for nouns, separated by 'or', in an interrogative?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions

Let S denote a singular noun and P a plural. Then ***in an interrogative***, how do you determine the verb's grammatical number? I recollect that I read a claim, possibly on ELU, that ***in a declarative sentence***, the verb's grammatical number is simply that of the closest noun.
[Are](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15769/50720) the foregoing claim and the following examples right?

1. Is <s>/Are</s> there any S or P?

2. Are <s>/is</s> there any P or S?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if we were provided a selection of real-life examples (the examples in the linked ELL question are unrealistic, which makes it hard to produce a judgment).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use this construction, albeit with a bit of work.

"Is there *a S*, or *any P*, on the shelf?"

For example, "Is there **a suit**, or [perhaps] **some nice clothes**, in the closet?"

"Are there *any P*, or *a S*, on the shelf?"

For example, "Are there **any snacks**, or [maybe] **an easy meal**, in the refrigerator?"

The commas help with the flow of the sentence - offering the second noun as an alternative to the one actually associated with the verb. The bracketed words further improve flow by distancing the disagreeing plural from the verb.

Also, it's important to add a second article to accompany the other noun when the plurality doesn't agree and the second noun requires an article.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so let's suppose S is "can" and P is "bottles".

— Is there any can or bottles on the shelf?

— Are there any can or bottles on the shelf?

— Is there any bottles or can on the shelf?

— Are there any bottles or can on the shelf?

The answer is that ALL of these are incorrect. The number of the verb is determined by the numbers of the nouns, which must match. And you do not use singular nouns with "any". Here are four correct expressions; each pair identical in meaning:

Is there a bottle or can on the shelf?
Is there a can or bottle on the shelf?

Are there any bottles or cans on the shelf?
Are there any cans or bottles on the shelf?

Comment: Your choice of *"cans"* and *"bottles"* is truly misleading. I guess that you would not recommend: *"Are there any rices or noodles I could make for dinner?"* nor *"Is there any rice or a noodle I could make for dinner?"*

Comment: No, I would not recommend those either. The simple singular and plural were all I tried to explain; I tried to keep it simple and strraightforward. In what way is my choice of can and bottles "misleading"? Because they are both countable? Both your examples could be group nouns. I welcome your explanation of how those might work.

Comment: No, the reason that *cans* and *bottles* are misleading is that they are perfectly parallel, and there is no reason to make one singular and the other plural. So that's why you say the pluralities have to match.  But if one of them is a group noun and the other isn't, or if one of them is naturally single and the other naturally plural (see Coty's answer) then your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: So that means that both Coty and I explained why, in various cases, the "foregoing claim and the following examples" are not correct." And he did a good job of explaining how the fix requires "a bit of work" if you mix count nouns and non-count nouns, or ones that are, as you say, naturally plural or naturally singular. So I agree that my answer is incomplete, in that it doesn't cover all cases. So is Coty's, in that it doesn't cover the simple cases that mine does. He had mine to build on, so he didn't need to mention those cases.

Comment: But mine was sufficient to prove what the questioner asked.  The claim is incorrect, and so were his examples.